# How to prevent Dropping an Image outside the form?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a chess board and I don't want to allow the user to Drag & Drop a chess piece (image) outside of the form.

Current Code:

```
private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.DoDragDrop(pb.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
private void PictureBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image = DragDropPreview(e);
    }
private void PictureBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
private void PictureBox_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image = null;
    }
```

Is it possible to prevent the user to drag the image out of the form ?

```
 private void frmChessBoard_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stop the Drag & Drop action
    }
```

Or is there a way of not allowing to drop the image outside of the form ?
I don't know if there are events outside a form that can be triggered.

Comment: Please put your darg drop codes here.

Comment: This is not a real problem, you'll never get the drop event.  The user knows this, the mouse cursor tells him.  The only wrinkle is that he might drag to another window that accepts images.  Which certainly is not unusual.  You fix that by wrapping the image in your own class and dragging an object of that class instead.  Only your code will be able to recognize it.